# how can i preload several background images on a div using a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

What is the best way to preload a background image on a div with a class using jQuery?

```
<div id="wrapper" class="first">

</div>


.first {background:url(/image.jpg) repeat-x top center}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pre-loaded them as regular images, either using the Image object or an IMG tag inside a hidden DIV. Then when you change the class of your working DIV to one that has a CSS background of one of your pre-loaded images it will pull it from the client cache.

```
.preload { display: none; }
...
<div>
    <img src="a.png" class="preload" />
    <img src="b.png" class="preload" />
</div>
```

Comment: they are background images. i'm not using `image tags` in my html markup

Comment: @BeEasy - Your question is "what is the best way...", my opinion is that using IMG tags is the best way (even if they are background images). There are a few different ways to do this but there is no way to force only CSS to preload images for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pre-load without changing your HTML markup, you can do this using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = "/image.jpg";
});
```

Comment: they are background images. i'm not using `image tags` in my html markup

Comment: @BeEasy This won't add any code to your markup. perhaps you misread my answer: `If you wish to pre-load without changing your HTML markup`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a whole image instead of using a number of separate image files and may make use of the xpos and ypos parameters of CSS background-position functionality. In this case just one image file is loaded and for once. And let CSS and the classes handle the rest of the stuff. Here is an example;

```
/*this is the style*/
<style type="text/css">
    .first {
        background: url(.....) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    }
    .second {
        background: url(.....) no-repeat -200px -200px;
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper" class="first"></div>
```

Comment: i wan't to avoid that because the images are `2000 x 1300`

Comment: Ok. I got your point. Do you have to use just one div element for that case? Unless you do, you may create multiple div elements and keep'em hidden until they're needed.

Comment: I'm using jquery to add the class to the `div#wrapper` each class has its own background image. i want to preload multiple classes (background images) so the background image is already loaded before the class changes.